# fragment loads layout but buttons and edittext not active

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I use several fragments in a swipe tabs. The last one I created shows up correctly in my app but clicking on buttons and edit text doesn't do anything. I think it is the way I created the fragment in studio.

How can I debug this situation?

I add the java code:

```
   public class StoreWords extends Fragment {

    public StoreWords() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_words_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    initFileSave();
    add_w_edit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_diffwords_edit);

    Button add = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_diffwords);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addWords();
        }
    });

    Button del = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.remove_diffwords);
    del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addWords();
        }
    });
}
```

and the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.bernard.speechparole.StoreWords"
    >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_words"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/add_diffwords"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/text_words"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/add_diffwords_edit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_diffwords"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/add_diffwords"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/remove_diffwords"
    android:text="@string/delete"
    android:layout_below="@+id/add_diffwords"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:id="@+id/list_words"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/remove_diffwords"
        />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like inside `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_words_fragment,
    container, false);
   Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_diffwords):
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                // your code here
             } 
   }); 
   return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class StoreWords extends Fragment {

    public StoreWords() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_words_fragment, container, false)
    add_w_edit = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.add_diffwords_edit);

    Button add = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.add_diffwords);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addWords();
        }
    });

    Button del = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.remove_diffwords);
    del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addWords();
        }
    });
    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    initFileSave();


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I think your 3 responses were driving to the same recommendation? My code is all like that: instantiating the buttons in onActivityCreated and it worked just fine. It is just that last fragment that I did which differs. Now, I did it as you say and I get the same result. I think there is a mismatch in the way I created the fragment. If you know the studio I did it on the main activity leading to the swipe tabs.

Comment: Many thanks guys. Instantiating the buttons method in onActivityCreated works. I fixed my problem by recreating the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you inflate layout of fragment but when you connect listeners to views you search them in activity layout.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_words_fragment, null, false);
   Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_diffwords):
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
              addWords();
           } 
   }); 

  //Other code and views that you want handle events

  return view;
}
```

Check this article how to work with fragments. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

When you call this 
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_diffwords); it means that you try to search and set listener to view in activity layout.